# How to change theme images over https?

Tags: wordpress, image, ssl, plugins, themes

I bought a theme to build my website. Now I secured my website through SSL, but in some of my website pages, I'm encountering some insecure mixed content. when I tried to pinpoint the problem, it is coming from my theme(My theme has an asset of images) which is out of my control. So how can I resolve this images over https?

Comment: Try using a plugin, something like "really simple SSL" might help. I think it replaces all non-https links to https.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze OP states that they have an "asset of images" that is out of their control. That may mean the images come from a 3rd party site; and more specifically one that does not support HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the theme having "http://" hardcoded into theme files, or wp-config.php. You have two options;

1. Run a programme like Notepad++ to search your theme's directory for all instances of "http://" and replace with "https://".
2. Install a plugin such as 'Really Simple SSL" which automatically changes http:// instances

Using your browsers' WebDev tools console, you'll also be able to see which images aren't loading, and usually it's quite clear that an image is trying to load over http:// rather than https://

Comment: OP's question is not clear enough to provide a correct answer.  OP states that they have an "asset of images" that is out of their control.  That may mean the images come from a 3rd party site; and more specifically one that does not support HTTPS.